What type of test should I run my data
Good day,
I have some data I am trying to analyze and want to make sure I run the appropriate test. My data consists in a set of samples which I inoculated with a pathogen in different days (I named these "Tests"), given sample availability, I had to randomize which samples where going to be inoculated in a given "Test" and included two controls to be present in all "Tests".
I attached an example of my data.



Test
Sample
Rep
Rating




1
A
1
1


1
A
2
1


1
B
1
3


1
B
2
3


1
C
1
2


1
C
2
2


1
D
1
4


1
D
2
3


1
CtrR
1
1


1
CtrR
2
1


1
CtrS
1
4


1
CtrS
2
4


2
A
1
1


2
A
2
2


2
E
1
4


2
E
2
4


2
F
1
4


2
F
2
4


2
G
1
2


2
G
2
3


2
CtrR
1
1


2
CtrR
2
1


2
CtrS
1
4


2
CtrS
2
4


3
A
1
1


3
A
2
1


3
B
1
3


3
B
2
2


3
F
1
4


3
F
2
3


3
G
1
2


3
G
2
2


3
CtrR
1
1


3
CtrR
2
2


3
CtrS
1
4


3
CtrS
2
4



The above data is just to hopefully give an example of the design, actual data is much larger in sample size as well as "Tests" and there was more reps of a sample within the same Test, but wanted to show an idea of the design. So, as you can see there will be samples that would have been replicated in multiple tests and some that could have been replicated in just one, my control being present in all Tests for sure.
I want to know if its ok for me to run lsmeans with a model such as:
lm(Rating~ Sample + Test + Sample*Test)
Or what would the best statistical analysis be in order to get means that would hopefully correct for samples not being represented in all "Tests" at the same time.
Also would like to ask if lsmeans is possible, could I also do a Tukey HSD to compare means between the different samples and see if there are any noticeable differences on how they rated?
Thanks.
